# Чем отличается Maven Apache от Maven Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea, maven

В чем значительная разница между Maven Apache, и встроенного Maven в IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 1):

Ничем не отличается. В IntelliJ IDEA встроен Apache Maven.

Answer (score 0):

В IDEA это всего лишь плагин, содержащий maven. Консолькой с мавеном можно воспользоваться прямо из идеи, плюс даётся GUI для того, чтобы не писать все команды в консоли.